# Web Server Says The Page Isn't Working And Won't Load Page

Tags: php

This is the entirety of the code that I have on this page. I've linked to the server connection, which works. Can't figure out what's wrong. Some input would be appreciated.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once("account-management/db_connect.php");
    
    
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_lister_id']) && ($_SESSION['email'])) {
            echo '<section class="topnavbar">';
            echo '<div id="top-login">';
            echo '<a href="#">Listing Profile</a> / <a href="#">Account Settings</a> / <a href="#">Case Requests</a>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</section>';
        } else {
            echo '<section class="topnavbar">';
            echo '<div id="top-register">';
            echo '<a href="#">Client Register</a> / <a href="#">Lister Register</a>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div id="top-login">';
            echo '<a href="#">Client Login</a> / <a href="#">Lister Login</a>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</section>';
        }
?>
            <section class="header-grid">
        <img src="../images/Logo.png" width="120" />
        <div id="ad-field">This content coming soon!</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Might be parse error or other in `db_connect.php`

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: There are no errors in the code you posted.

Comment: It tells me the website is currently unable to handle the request. HTTP Error 500. The HTTP status code 500 is a generic error response. It means that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. This error is usually returned by the server when no other error code is suitable.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: You can either check the error logs or add `error_reporting(-1);` after session_start and see the error on page. Probably the error is related to the file you are adding as @AbraCadaver told.  Without error information unfortunately no one can give you more help.

Comment: I checked the error file. To be honest, I didn't know that this useful file was available. Thanks for pointing it out! The error file stated that it failed to open the require_once file listed at the top of the page. This is odd because this is in fact the path for this file. I tried changing it to a direct file path at one point, but that didn't work either. I do have an idea. I've been having all sorts of problems with it since I moved it into a folder. Maybe if I move it back into public_html....

Comment: So what I did was put a copy of my database connection file in each individual folder that contains files and now it seems to be working. Didn't know the connection had to be in the same folder.